# HTTP/2 download speed is much slower than HTTP/1.1 with HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-core, http2

When I am downloading file with HTTP/2 speed is locked to 16 mbps. Speed with HTTP/1.1 - 90 mbps. Code is very simple:

```cs
var url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxxxxxxxx/o/xxx.xxx?alt=media&token=xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx";
using var client = new HttpClient() { DefaultRequestVersion = new Version(2, 0) };
using var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
```

I tested it with my PC and laptop (both Windows 10) using different ISPs and another sources with HTTP/2 support - same behavior.

If I am downloading this file by any browser - HTTP/2 speed is same as HTTP/1.1 speed. Although Edge shows "http/2.0+quic/46" protocol.

Also I gave this code to my friend in another city and he doesn't have such problem.

What is the reason of this problem? Can ISP slow down HTTP/2 traffic somehow?

UPD: Same problem with .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5

Comment: Have you tested it with other websites? Or is it specific to this one?

Comment: The speed for downloading binary files must be the same for both HTTP versions. ISP technically can throttle the speed with ALG but i have no idea why it may do it. Try different web server. Btw in case you reading the `response` as `Stream`, consider `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` with `ConfigureAwait(false)`. In case of regular (not binary files) HTTP traffic, setup GZip `Accept-Encoding` support. For test purpose you may setup request headers similar to web browser's.

Comment: @mjwills Yes, I tried with another websites and also with own website with nginx on GCE

Comment: @aepot `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` and reading as `Stream` didn't help too. Yes I tried to set all headers which browser sends in request (including Accept-Encoding) - nothing

Comment: `Also I gave this code to my friend in another city and he doesn't have such problem.` It is likely related to your ISP then.

Comment: Please provide a mininal reproducible example.

Comment: @mjwills I think it is ISP too, but it doesn't affect browsers somehow. May be there is some option that I missed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and was directed to [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/43086).

That appears to be the likely culprit. There is no fix, but it looks like they are [tracking this for .NET 6 later this year](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/46850).

The best workaround seems to be to use a separate HTTP/1.1 client instance for downloads larger than 64 KB.